# Prototyping extern function in Visual C++

Tags: c, winapi, dll, prototyping

I have some exe application. This app has an exporting table and export a bunch of functions. I'd like to use some of them. For example, I need to use ABS function. I opened Ida Pro, looked at pseudocode, and i have the next one:

```
double __cdecl ABS(double *a1, double *a2)
{
 if ( *a2 < 0.0 )
 {
   *a1 = -1.0 * *a2;
 }
 else
 {
   *a1 = *a2;
   *(a1 + 4) = *(a2 + 4);
 }
 return *a1;
}
```

Then i wrote prototype:

```
typedef double (*ABS)(double *,double *);

int _tmain(int argc,_TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HINSTANCE hMod = LoadLibrary(L"exe.exe");
    if (hMod!=NULL)
    {
        ABS func = (ABS)GetProcAddress(HMod,"ABS");
        if (func!=NULL)
        {
            double x=0;
            double y =-2;
            double z = func(&x,&y);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

prototype in my project:

```
typedef double (*ABS)(double *, double *);
```

ok, hMod and func not NULL, but al a result I have  an error (while reading memory) or some not right values. (exmpl: 483435, -343524)
Help me, please, to correct this situation

Here origin Ida pro pseudosode:

```
double __cdecl ABS(int a1, int a2)
{
  if ( *(double *)a2 < 0.0 )
  {
    *(double *)a1 = -1.0 * *(double *)a2;
  }
  else
  {
    *(_DWORD *)a1 = *(_DWORD *)a2;
    *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 4) = *(_DWORD *)(a2 + 4);
  }
  return *(double *)a1;
}
```

I thought it is equal to my optimization

PS: `*(a1 + 4) = *(a2 + 4);` is not means that we move address? Becouse we move pointer values

Comment: btw, calling LoadLibrary on an .exe file seems to be just plain old backwards. Don't get in the habit of doing that. compile it into a DLL instead.

Comment: That's a pretty scary ABS function - if `a2` is negative, it stores `-a2` into `a1`, but if it's not, it copies `a2` into `a1` as well as copying the a `double`-sized chunk of memory from after `a2` to after `a1`, skipping 3 intervening `double`-sized values....?